# Default VFAT Driver Options On Auto-Mount

Tags: opensuse, automount

The Auto-Mount behavior on OpenSUSE 11.2 64-bit system automatically attaches USB drives and Flash memory cards with the default VFAT option to ignore filename case.

How do I change it so that Automount uses the shortname=mixed option VFAT driver option instead?

This used to work in prior versions with gconf but is no longer the case. Basically I am looking to see if anyone has a workaround for the following bug:
https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=550454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the bug is correct, there's no way to change the automounting behavior.

The only workaround is to unmount and mount it manually, e.g.:

```
[patches@unicornland ~]$ df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                29259876   8200264  20762412  29% /
udev                    999304         0    999304   0% /dev
tmpfs                  1008552       516   1008036   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  1008552       744   1007808   1% /run
/dev/sda5             29259876   8200264  20762412  29% /
tmpfs                  1008552         0   1008552   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                  1008552         0   1008552   0% /media
/dev/sda1            103212320  46943228  51026216  48% /home
/dev/sdb1              1920704   1908032     12672 100% /media/192E-0596
#now we know /media/192E-0586 is on /dev/sdb1 so we can unmount it
[patches@unicornland ~]$ udisks --unmount /dev/sdb1
#and remount it with the option we want
[patches@unicornland ~]$ udisks --mount /dev/sdb1 --mount-options shortname=mixed
Mounted /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sdb1 at /media/192E-0596
```

Comment: That is what I've been doing. Thank you for confirming.

Comment: @Itai:  Another workaround might be to [write `udev` rules to mount the disk](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Mount_under_.2Fmedia.3B_use_partition_label_if_present), adapting the line regarding mount options to your needs.  I'm not sure if that will race with `udisks`/GNOME or not, however.